# Symfony authenticator: In controllers, Doctrine returns user item with empty string field, although a value is set

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.4, doctrine-query

My database schema consists mainly of the following entities: user and auth_token. Each user can have multiple auth_token's.

The problem: when selecting the currently authenticated user in a controller, the string field saltedPasswordHash is empty (""), although a value is set in the database. Getting saltedPasswordHash in the ApiKeyAuthenticator.php works (please have a look at the two TODO comments).

For whatever reason, selecting the email (string) or created (datetime) field works. Persisting new user entities with a saltedPasswordHash or selecting any other user item works fine.

An APIKeyAuthenticator is handling the authorization. When disabling firewall and authentication, everything works as expected. I included the source files below.

I'm using PHP 7.2.15-1 with mysql Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.13-MariaDB.

**Security/ApiKeyAuthenticator.php**

```
namespace App\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\PreAuthenticatedToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface;

class ApiKeyAuthenticator implements SimplePreAuthenticatorInterface
{
    public function createToken(Request $request, $providerKey)
    {
        $apiKey = $request->headers->get('authToken');

        if (!$apiKey) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException();

            // or to just skip api key authentication
            // return null;
        }

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            'anon.',
            $apiKey,
            $providerKey
        );
    }

    public function supportsToken(TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return $token instanceof PreAuthenticatedToken && $token->getProviderKey() === $providerKey;
    }

    public function authenticateToken(TokenInterface $token, UserProviderInterface $userProvider, $providerKey)
    {
        if (!$userProvider instanceof ApiKeyUserProvider) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf(
                    'The user provider must be an instance of ApiKeyUserProvider (%s was given).',
                    get_class($userProvider)
                )
            );
        }

        $apiKey = $token->getCredentials();
        $username = $userProvider->getUsernameForApiKey($apiKey);

        if (!$username) {
            // CAUTION: this message will be returned to the client
            // (so don't put any un-trusted messages / error strings here)
            throw new BadCredentialsException(
                sprintf('API Key "%s" does not exist.', $apiKey)
            );
        }

        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByAuthToken($apiKey);

        if (!isset($user)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(
                sprintf('API Key "%s" does not exist.', $apiKey)
            );
        }

        // TODO: HERE, THE $user->getSaltedPasswordHash() RETURNS THE CORRECT VALUE!

        return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
            $user, // TODO: with "new User()" instead, it works!
            $apiKey,
            $providerKey,
            $user->getRoles()
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        return new Response(
        // this contains information about *why* authentication failed
        // use it, or return your own message
            strtr($exception->getMessageKey(), $exception->getMessageData()),
            401
        );
    }
}
```

**Security/ApiKeyUserProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\AuthToken;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UnsupportedUserException;

class ApiKeyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * ApiKeyUserProvider constructor.
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getUsernameForApiKey($apiKey)
    {
        return $apiKey;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        // TODO: Implement loadUserByUsername() method.
    }

    /**
     * Auth token is used as username
     *
     * @param string $authToken
     * @return null|UserInterface
     */
    public function loadUserByAuthToken($authToken): ?UserInterface
    {
        if (!isset($authToken)) {
            return null;
        }

        $token = $this->em
            ->getRepository(AuthToken::class)
            ->findOneBy(['id' => AuthToken::hex2dec($authToken)]);

        if (!isset($token)) {
            return null;
        }

        return $token->getUser();
    }

    public
    function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // this is used for storing authentication in the session
        // but in this example, the token is sent in each request,
        // so authentication can be stateless. Throwing this exception
        // is proper to make things stateless
        throw new UnsupportedUserException();
    }

    public
    function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

**Entity/User.php**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * This needs to be nullable because the email includes the id of newly created users, which can only be obtained after inserting the new record.
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=true)
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * Set null to disable login
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(max=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $saltedPasswordHash;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\AuthToken", mappedBy="user", fetch="LAZY")
     */
    private $authTokens;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5)
     */
    private $role;

    // ...

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->role = 'user';
        $this->saltedPasswordHash = null;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSaltedPasswordHash(): ?string
    {
        return $this->saltedPasswordHash;
    }

    public function setSaltedPasswordHash(?string $saltedPasswordHash): self
    {
        $this->saltedPasswordHash = $saltedPasswordHash;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(?string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreated(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->created;
    }

    public function setCreated(\DateTimeInterface $created): self
    {
        $this->created = $created;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getAuthTokens()
    {
        return $this->authTokens;
    }

    /**
     * @param ArrayCollection $authTokens
     * @return User
     */
    public function setAuthTokens(ArrayCollection $authTokens): User
    {
        $this->authTokens = $authTokens;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param AuthToken $authToken
     * @return User
     */
    public function addAuthToken(AuthToken $authToken): User
    {
        $this->authTokens->add($authToken);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param AuthToken $authToken
     * @return User
     */
    public function removeAuthToken(AuthToken $authToken): User
    {
        $this->authTokens->removeElement($authToken);

        return $this;
    }

    // ...

    /**
     * Returns the password used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * This should be the encoded password. On authentication, a plain-text
     * password will be salted, encoded, and then compared to this value.
     *
     * @return string The password
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->getSaltedPasswordHash();
    }

    /**
     * Returns the salt that was originally used to encode the password.
     *
     * This can return null if the password was not encoded using a salt.
     *
     * @return string|null The salt
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    /**
     * Returns the username used to authenticate the user.
     *
     * @return string The username
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->getEmail();
    }

    /**
     * Removes sensitive data from the user.
     *
     * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
     * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->setSaltedPasswordHash('');
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getRole()
    {
        return $this->role;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $role
     * @return User
     */
    public function setRole($role): User
    {
        $this->role = $role;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "User " . $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * The equality comparison should neither be done by referential equality
     * nor by comparing identities (i.e. getId() === getId()).
     *
     * However, you do not need to compare every attribute, but only those that
     * are relevant for assessing whether re-authentication is required.
     *
     * Also implementation should consider that $user instance may implement
     * the extended user interface `AdvancedUserInterface`.
     *
     * https://stackoverflow.com/a/39884792/6144818
     *
     * @param UserInterface $user
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return (
                $this->getUsername() == $user->getUsername()
            ) && (
                $this->getRoles() == $user->getRoles()
            );
    }

    // ...
}
```

**Entitiy/AuthToken.php**

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AuthTokenRepository")
 */
class AuthToken
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=32, scale=0, options={"unsigned": true})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="authTokens")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $added;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $lastSeen;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=12, nullable=true)
     */
    private $apiVersion;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHexId(): string
    {
        return $this->dec2hex($this->id);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function generateId(): void
    {
        $length = 32;

        $str = "";
        $characters = range('0', '9');
        $max = count($characters) - 1;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $rand = random_int(0, $max);
            $str .= $characters[$rand];
        }

        $this->id = $str;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $user
     */
    public function setUser($user): void
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAdded()
    {
        return $this->added;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $added
     */
    public function setAdded($added): void
    {
        $this->added = $added;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getLastSeen()
    {
        return $this->lastSeen;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $lastSeen
     */
    public function setLastSeen($lastSeen): void
    {
        $this->lastSeen = $lastSeen;
    }

    public function getApiVersion(): ?string
    {
        return $this->apiVersion;
    }

    public function setApiVersion(string $apiVersion): self
    {
        $this->apiVersion = $apiVersion;

        return $this;
    }

    public static function dec2hex(string $dec): string
    {
        $hex = '';
        do {
            $last = bcmod($dec, 16);
            $hex = dechex($last) . $hex;
            $dec = bcdiv(bcsub($dec, $last), 16);
        } while ($dec > 0);
        return $hex;
    }

    public static function hex2dec($hex)
    {
        $dec = '0';
        $len = strlen($hex);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++)
            $dec = bcadd($dec, bcmul(strval(hexdec($hex[$i - 1])), bcpow('16', strval($len - $i))));

        return $dec;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return "AuthToken " . $this->id . " (" . $this->user . ")";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function of your *Entity/User.php* is the reason of your behavior:

```
/**
 * Removes sensitive data from the user.
 *
 * This is important if, at any given point, sensitive information like
 * the plain-text password is stored on this object.
 */
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    $this->setSaltedPasswordHash('');
}
```

When authentication comes in play on Symfony, after the authentication, [the AuthenticationProviderManager would call that `eraseCredentials` function](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f834c9262b411aa5793fcea23694e3ad3b5acbb4/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationProviderManager.php#L92), so it doesn't leak sensible information, or even worse, the sensible information does not end up in your session.

Just try to comment the setter in that function and you should have what you expect.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much!