# How to prevent user from being unauthenticated after dynamic password change

Tags: php, symfony4

The problem is when I **change user password** in my database while I'm logged in, my user becomes **unauthenticated** after refreshing the page.

It causes **too many redirects** error in my browser because my root controller is trying to redirect to controller which is protected by `@Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')")` annotation.

*SecurityController.php*

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="app_login")
 */
public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
{
    // (...)
    return $this->redirectToRoute('admin');
}
```

*AdminController.php*

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin", name="admin")
 * @Security("is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')", message="403 Access denied")
 */
public function index()
{
    // (...)
}
```

After refreshing `/admin` view (or every other view) it fails to authenticate current user due to `@Security` annotation and it falls back to root controller when the infinite redirect loop begins.

How to prevent Symfony from changing user status on password change while being logged in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Prelude

1. Symfony authenticate user on every request, so it calls `getPassword()` method from user entity each time you refresh the view.
2. Symfony stores only post authenticated (logged in) user data (also password hash) in serialized token `PostAuthenticationGuardToken` in `'_security_main'` session key and also every (normal or anonymous) authenticated user token inside container. To see data inside specific token use:

   1. `dump(\unserialize($request->getSession()->get('_security_main')));` for logged in user
   2. `dump($this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken());` for every user
3. When you change password in your database and you are logged in at the same time the `PostAuthenticationGuardToken` user token is changed to `AnonymousToken` and because of that `is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')` fails.

---

## Behind the scenes

Check out namespace `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token`: https://github.com/symfony/security-core/tree/4.2/Authentication/Token.
*Click it so info below becomes 150% easier.*

There is `AbstractToken` class that is base for `PostAuthenticationGuardToken` and `AnonymousToken`. `AbstractToken` has `hasUserChanged(UserInterface $user)` method that determines whether user sensitive data has changed.
Inside this class is another method `setUser($user)` that determines whether user should be authenticated (**also** based on `hasUserChanged`) and it sets user entity for token class that extends this class.

*AbstractToken.php*

```
if ($changed) {
    $this->setAuthenticated(false);
}
```

Unauthenticated user after password change?! Yes but only for abstract class.
Normal user as well as anonymous user are authenticated. Very easy:

*AnonymousToken.php*

```
class AnonymousToken extends AbstractToken
{
    private $secret;

    public function __construct(string $secret, $user, array $roles = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($roles);
        $this->secret = $secret;
        $this->setUser($user);
        $this->setAuthenticated(true); // here you go :-)
    }
    // (...)
```

Now the actual `if` that makes all the problems...

*AbstractToken.php*

```
if ($this->user->getPassword() !== $user->getPassword()) {
    return true;
}
```

*compares user stored in the session, and the one returned by the refreshUser of your provider.*
[Symfony & Guard: "The security token was removed due to an AccountStatusException"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880051/symfony-guard-the-security-token-was-removed-due-to-an-accountstatusexceptio#answer-39884792)

---

## Solution

credits to: [Alain Tiemblo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/731138/alain-tiemblo)

Implement `EquatableInterface` in you user entity

*User.php*

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\{UserInterface, EquatableInterface};

class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface
{
// (...)
}
```

Override `isEqualTo` method from this interface

*User.php*

```
public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user)
{
    return $user->getId() === $this->getId();
}
```

**Done**. Now each time `hasUserChanged` is called when you have password changed in your database, the password check `if` is not executed.
Prove:

*AbstractToken.php*

```
private function hasUserChanged(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!($this->user instanceof UserInterface)) {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException('Method "hasUserChanged" should be called when current user class is instance of "UserInterface".');
    }

    if ($this->user instanceof EquatableInterface) {
        return !(bool) $this->user->isEqualTo($user);
// THIS is executed and FALSE is returned because user instances have the same ids but different passwords :)
    }

    if ($this->user->getPassword() !== $user->getPassword()) {
        return true;
    }

    // other checks like salt or username below
```

Now you can back to prelude 2.1 and 2.2 and check results.